# How is the witch Queen the Mother of all witches

Tags: black-clover

> In Black Clover episode 57; when Vanessa went back to the witches forest in order to help remove the curse on Asta's hand, the witch queen states herself that she is the mother of all the witches in the forest and they are all her descendants.

The statement made by the Witch Queen really confuses me because i'm not sure if she meant it literally or figuratively, Assuming that statement was made literally then **how did she create/give birth to all the witches since she stated that she hates men and imperfections.**